# Problems installing Nitro Application?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dependencies, nitro

I installed Nitro using `apt-get`. However, it is dependent of `gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0` and is missing. How can I get the source code of `gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0` somehow and install it on my computer?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install nitro
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nitro : Depends: gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It does not work if you want to try to install it at the Ubuntu Application Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Nitro

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/nitrotasks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nitrotasks
```

I have just install Nitro on my Ubuntu 13.04 and its working ....